# req.user undefined in other model

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have 2 modules

1. users
2. blogs

i have implemented users for login register with passport authentication . When i try to use current user data(req.user) in blog model it results 'undefined'.

i have share my code below

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app =express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const Users = require("./routes/Users");
const Blogs = require("./routes/Blog");
app.use("/users",Users);
app.use("/blogs",Blogs);

app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started...');
});
```

**users.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const express=require('express');
const users = express.Router();
const models = require('../models');
const User = models.users;

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

users.use(cookieParser());
users.use(session({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
users.use(passport.initialize());
users.use(passport.session());

require('../config/passport.js')(passport, User); 

users.post('/register',passport.authenticate('local-register', {
        successRedirect: '/users/profile', 
        failureRedirect: '/users/register'
    }
));

users.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        session: true,
        successRedirect: '/users/profile', 
        failureRedirect: '/users/profile'
    }
));

module.exports =users;
```

**blogs.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const blogs = express.Router();
const blogModel = require('../models/blogs');


blogs.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.user) // RESULTS UNDEFINED
    res.send('Blog List');
});
```

**passport.js**

```
const bCrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport, user) { 
    const User = user;  

    passport.use('local-register', new LocalStrategy( { usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password', passReqToCallback: true },  
        function(req, email, password, done) { 
             ... ....

        } 
    ));

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email',  passwordField: 'password',   passReqToCallback: true },  
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        .....  .....
    }   
)); 

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => { 
    done(null, user.id); 
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => { 
    const User =user;
    User.findById(id).then((user) =>{ 
        if (user) { 
            done(null, user);
        } else { 
            done(user.errors, null);
         } 
    }); 
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initiating `passport` (which handles `req.user`) only for `Users` router, this way only routes starting with `/users` will actually have access to `req.user`.

In order to use `req.user` inside the `Blogs` module, you need to initiate `passport` for the entire `express` app (instead of just the users router).

You would probably want to move the initialization to the `app.js` file

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is you are using multiple objects/instance of express packages and trying to pass from one to another. It won't work as expected. To make it working you should have multiple routes using the same express instance.

Comment: Create 1 object of express and pass that to multiple files and use that object. It will work I believe.

Comment: @naranyansharama +1 for your solution , it solves my other problem. thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that. Please mark as correct answer. So that others can take advantages of this.